# How to set .apk file name and package in build.gradle? Android Gradle plugin 3.0

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-gradle-3.0

According to my CI requirements I'm trying to achieve two things:

- set apk file name in format: .apk
- set folder for generated .apk file: app/build/outputs/apk/myBuild.apk

I used android gradle plugin 2.3 and got following script to manage task above (it worked correctly for gradle plugin 2.3):

```
applicationVariants.all {
        variant ->
            variant.outputs.each { output ->
                output.outputFile = new File(
                        output.outputFile.parent,
                        variant.productFlavors.get(0).name + variant.buildType.name + ".apk")
            }
```

Now I got the following code (according to latest updates in android gradle plugin 3.0):

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.all { output ->
            logger.debug("fileNameParent", output.outputFile.parent)
            outputFileName = new File(
                    "apk/",
                    outputFileName.replace(".apk", "MyBuild.apk"))
        }
```

And got following structure (see picture):

[image]

P.S. I read Android Gradle Plugin migration guide, but it doesn't help me to achieve my goal :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first part of the question: how to generate filename.

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.all { output ->
            outputFileName = new File("${variant.productFlavors.get(0).name}${variant.buildType.name}.apk")
        }
```

The second part of the question: how to set path.

According to [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html) it's impossible:

> Using the Variant API to manipulate variant outputs is broken with the
>   new plugin. It still works for simple tasks, such as changing the APK
>   name during build time...  However, more complicated tasks that
>   involve accessing outputFile objects no longer work. That's because
>   variant-specific tasks are no longer created during the configuration
>   stage.

Comment: It worked on older version, how to achieve it now as it does not work on new versions?

Answer (score -1):

this is the correct code:

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.all{
        outputFileName = outputFileName.replace("app-${variant.buildType.name}.apk", ${variant.productFlavors.get(0).name} + "-" + ${variant.buildType.name} + ".apk")
    }
}
```

please keep in mind that you have to put this code in build.gradle app file on *android{ }* section, and not on *android{ buildTypes{ debug/release{ }}}* sections

This will return for:

debug build:

> app-debug.apk >> YOUR_PRODUCT_NAME-debug.apk

release build:

> app-release.apk >> YOUR_PRODUCT_NAME-release.apk

don't use **outputFileName = new File()** or you have the problem of variant API manipulation

Comment: Why should I replace file Instead of creating file? I've tested code above and it's working as expected.

Comment: I've tested code above and it's working as expected. Please explain which manipulation do you mean.

Comment: Hi @SlavaSotone I mean variant API manipulations (of gradle plugin v3.0.0) that you linked in your post: [link](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html)